# Resetting state after dynamically updating JavaScript in an IFRAME

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple web application that dynamically creates a web page comprising of HTML, JavaScript and CSS. Via some rudimentary UI in one `IFRAME`, I let the user select options and then create the page each time something changes in another `IFRAME`. I rebuild the page with code like this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('output_frame');
iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html_content);
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
```

It works pretty well for the static content but I also include a bunch of third party libs and whilst the functionality the provide works okay the first time the page is created, on subsequent changes, they break. For example, a frame rate counter starts at 60hz or thereabouts but goes up rapidly after each change / update cycle.

When I write the page out to disk and load it normally, everything is okay of course.

I imagine it's because updating the iframe that way isn't nearly the same as a page load and doesn't reset everything it needs to.

I tried calling `reload(true)` on the `IFRAME.contentWindow` after the content changed but that didn't appear to help at all.

Should I be updating the `IFRAME` in a different manner and if not, is there a way to reset the state between updates.

Thank you.

Comment: Probably the easiest workaround could be to replace the `iframe` element itself with a new one … that should get rid of any “artifacts” that might cling to that window instance from previous iterations.

Comment: Thank you CBroe - I hadn't considered that approach but a quick test suggests it might work. Seems to be a lot slower and JavaScript mouse functions in the output no longer work but that might be fixed if I manage the lifetime of the IFRAME a bit better. I'll dig into it more tonight and mark as the answer if I get everything working. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the code I had before that partially worked:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('output_frame');
iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html_content);
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
```

with this code and things now work as expected. Thank you @CBroe

```
// remove old frame
var old_iframe = document.getElementById('output_frame');
old_iframe.parentNode.removeChild(old_iframe);

// create new one - CSS takes care of position, size etc.
var new_iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
new_iframe.id = "output_frame";
new_iframe.frameBorder = 0;

// update the contents
document.body.appendChild(new_iframe);
new_iframe.contentWindow.document.open()
new_iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html_content);
new_iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
```

It seems to be a little slower but now, anything with JavaScript that I load as part of the page works as expected.